# Importing nodes with Node export is creating them in "unpublished" status

Tags: importing-exporting

I'm importing content from one D7 site to another using the Node export module. However, when importing the content in the new site, the nodes are getting created in unpublished state. I have to publish them manually.

How can I have Drupal import the nodes in published state?

Answer (score 0):

At admin/config/content/node_export there is Reset values on import > [your node type] > Published checkbox, which is not checked by default. Checking this will **reset** the published status, which means nodes will be **unpublished** (that's how I interpret that anyway). So leaving it unchecked will not change the status. There seems to be no way to force nodes to be published.

If needed, on the new site nodes can be mass published at admin/content.